# How to debug connection from computer to server, server-side

Tags: django, apache, centos7

My Centos 7 server is running apache 2.4.6, and is serving up a django webapp using mod_wsgi.  My problem is that I cannot access the server url from my browser from another computer.  I am not getting any errors from apache and its up and running no problem. I've set the error logs to 'debug' in the http.conf file but still no errors.  I know the server is in fact connected to the internet by pinging it, i know it is listening on port :80 by running

`netstat -tunlp | grep 80`.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60080           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3841/name-gu 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      13882/httpd
```

I have temporarily turned off all firewalls server-side as well

My settings.py has the url, ip address, and localhost under `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

How do i debug this issue so i have an error i can look into?

---

**Log**:
Let me know if more information is need
ran `tcpdump -nn tcp port 80` on server computer
then ran `curl -v myurl.com` on my machine and get these results on my server:

```
13:11:52.225076 IP 10.0.24.67.40658 > 10.0.26.20.80: Flags [S], seq 3327782620, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 36451589 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:11:52.225355 IP 10.0.26.20.80 > 10.0.24.67.40658: Flags [S.], seq 1689726058, ack 3327782621, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 73904848 ecr 36451589,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:11:52.225960 IP 10.0.24.67.40658 > 10.0.26.20.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 36451590 ecr 73904848], length 0
13:11:52.226198 IP 10.0.24.67.40658 > 10.0.26.20.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:101, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 36451590 ecr 73904848], length 100: HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1
13:11:52.226448 IP 10.0.26.20.80 > 10.0.24.67.40658: Flags [.], ack 101, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 73904849 ecr 36451590], length 0
13:11:52.231414 IP 10.0.26.20.80 > 10.0.24.67.40658: Flags [P.], seq 1:286, ack 101, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 73904854 ecr 36451590], length 285: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
13:11:52.232052 IP 10.0.24.67.40658 > 10.0.26.20.80: Flags [.], ack 286, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 36451596 ecr 73904854], length 0
13:11:52.232814 IP 10.0.24.67.40658 > 10.0.26.20.80: Flags [F.], seq 101, ack 286, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 36451597 ecr 73904854], length 0
13:11:52.233003 IP 10.0.26.20.80 > 10.0.24.67.40658: Flags [F.], seq 286, ack 102, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 73904856 ecr 36451597], length 0
13:11:52.233414 IP 10.0.24.67.40658 > 10.0.26.20.80: Flags [.], ack 287, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 36451597 ecr 73904856], length 0
```

Comment: What you mean by "cannot access the server"? Do you get a timeout or an http status code >= 400 or an OK (200) response with an empty body? You can check it by "inspect / network" in the browser or better by a command line utility directly on the server, without need to disable the firewall. E.g. by the command `curl -i http://mysite.example.com`. You can also see the status code in `/var/log/http/access_log`.

Comment: These ten packets are a normal communication for a small HTTP GET request with a small response. Packets with flags [S] (syn), ack (acknowledgment) and [F] (fin) are only for handshake to initialize a TCP connection, confirm received packets and to close the connection correctly. Only two packets have nonzero length and they have very clear comments: `HTTP: GET / HTTP/1.1` and `HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK`. You can send the same request by your browser and leave only this communication here.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "You can send the same request by your browser and leave only this communication here." How can i send the same request to the browser, when my browser doesn't accept or send requests to the server?

Comment: I wrote it to can really sure that no packet is sent from your browser and that the problem is not related to Apache, Django or CentOS, even not to the server at all. The text "Blocked... unsecured network" indicates that it is related to some security policy. It is off topic for me now. It is more a question for your network administrator. You probably also could not open a web interface of any device (like a network printer) on that network in the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I would focus on verify that you can access some static test page on your Apache server, because it is listening only on an **IPv6** port. (It is the most suspicious detail presented on your server. Maybe you configured only a DNS for an **IPv4** address or you did not also ping6 on the IPv6 address. If it is a public server then it should probably listen finally on IPv4 also. It's clear that no service is listening on IPv4 tcp port 80, neither a proxy.) If it was not the problem then I will describe a strategy "debugging":

... Great, you checked some useful particular facts, but the most effective strategy is to try to **bisect** a big area of possible problems to "half" sized areas that can be checked independently whether they work or don't work and how it would manifest itself specifically if anything in that area is broken.

I would look in **access log** `/var/log/httpd/access_log` (default Apache log on CentOS) that a request has been received by Apache and what was the status code and that the size of response was zero or nonzero and that everything is ok between Apache and a browser. It is more useful to easily test the server first by one request **from the same server**, before you start to suspect a firewall etc., e.g. test it by a command line utility `wget -S -O - http://mysite.example.com` or `curl -i http://mysite.example.com`. If you check anything by a browser you should use **developer tools** Inspect (Ctrl+Shift+I), Network tab and see if the problem is related only to a response or still to sending the request.

I would eventually also verify that the logging from Python/Django works and that you are looking into the right **Python log**, e.g. by adding a `log.info("something")` command at the end of `models.py`, not only that you don't see any error.

The text "I cannot access the server url from my browser" requires more information what is exactly meant by it. Literally it would mean that the problem would not be related to Django/Python, but between Apache and browser, if it really can not start to connect and send headers of a request. A missing response requires to consider primarily Django/Python. Even an unconfigured Apache shows a test page and can be accessed by ip address, without a valid DNS: http;//numeric.ip.address. You may verify that you can configure temporarily a simple test static site on the same domain...

**EDIT** The debugging continued by responses and suggestion in comments and by added formatted log in the question. The logical process is more important than only a resume.

Comment: Thank you for this, i actually have run `curl -i mysite.com` and recognizes the apache server, and my access_logs say a 301 error and upon inspection it says that it routes to another location given by the header like so `location: mysite.com` which matches my ip and dns points that to `mysite.com` ..... and this server is only accessible under the same network that the server is connected to so would i need a ipv4 connection if this is true? i also am unable to connect to test server on my production server

Comment: If you get a response from `ping6 mysite.com` running from public internet then you probably succeed soon with configuring your server for yourself, but the need of IPv4 depends finally also on your users. An estimated 25% users need IPv4. As regards redirection, it can be caused by Apache config if you don't see a redirection in the Python log or by Python if you see it there....

Comment: I still recommend to configure a test static site test.mysite.com on the production server with only one index.html file in the root and with a DNS that is resolved only to a public IPv6 address, if you want your Apache to be listening only on IPv6. Test it by `host test.mysite.com`. When it start to work reliably, continue with Django matter.

Comment: So i able to get a 200 status code running a test.html site, and able to `curl -i mysite.com` from both my server and my seperate computer. but still am unable to connect through browser

Comment: And change it to ipv4 connection by replacing `Listen 80` to `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` and still no luck, i have no idea where to go from here

Comment: I wrote more hints not used yet, e.g. to be familiar with developer tools / Network in the browser, to know what means "unable to connect". Try to verify every change, that it is active still, especially what regards DNS and DNS cache. Maybe try a browser and the command line utility on the same computer. Use a verbose `curl -v ...` to see that it is connecting to the right IPv4 or IPv6 address. Visit a page https://test-ipv6.com/  to see that the browser and network passed all tests for IPv6.

Comment: Try it from another network or another computer, also from Linux that has more diagnostics tools and maybe as the last resort, if something is complicated in the network routing or firewalls, Install "tcpdump" on both computers and run e.g. `tcpdump -nn tcp port 80` that you are receiving request and response packets from the right computer.

Comment: I have looked into the inspection tool under networking, it doesn't say much but except `Blocked: 1ms` and saying its an unsecured network.  The website you give me says that my DNS server has an ipv6 internet access.  I am unable to `curl myurl.com` when i change my server to a ipv4 connection, but can when my server is talking on a ipv6.  i ran `tcpdump -nn tcp port 80` on my server and ran `curl -v myurl.com` on my machine, and its recieving and giving http responses with no errors, check edit

Comment: It may help to say that these are private ip's under the same LAN (my server, and my computer)

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because this is the proper way to debug,  My problem was with the security policy as you said... I needed a proper ssl certificate

Comment: Thank you for the courage to try also unpleasant steps. I was for the first time for me that the communication continued after them. I believed in your courage when I was reading the word "debug".